# Theory Javascript concept or a polyfill for avoid non-expected behaviours?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, theory

I am very curious for know about it the following code is a "theory Javascript concept" or "A Polyfill for avoid non-expected behaviours".

```
function checkMyMoneyAt6am(_money){
  if(typeof _money !== 'number' ) return false

  //Do something ...
}
```

Questions:

- The way or technique that i use to avoid execute my internal algorithm returning a false value (or whatever) have a name?
- Do you believe that this code using this technique it's a unit-testable code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the two quoted terms?

Comment: early return or guard clause? and how it this make the function not unit-testable at all?